# Formatting a date retrieved from Wikidata

Tags: date, format, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikidata

So let's say I have an Infobox template in Wikipedia that retrieves a company foundation date from Wikidata. It contains the following code:

```
|label7 = Year founded
|text7 = {{wikidata|p571|{{{founded|}}}}}
```

My problem is that what's retrieved is formatted as `31 January 2010` and it looks weird next to "Year founded' since it is not a year but the whole date. Of course I could rename the label from "Year founded" to "Date founded" and *voila*, problem solved, right? But I do want to just get the year from Wikidata, not the whole date.

What would be the code for this? I imagine something like `{{wikidata|p571[year]|{{{founded|}}}}}` or `{{wikidata|p571[0]|{{{founded|}}}}}` or `{{wikidata|p571[YYYY]|{{{founded|}}}}}`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are probably nicer methods but as a last resort you can always use `{{#time}}`.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't sound like a programming question, but it looks like you can request a specific date format as the third parameter to wikidata
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module:Wikidata#Testing_getValue.2C_getRawValue_and_getDateValue

```
{{#invoke:Wikidata|getDateValue|P569|FETCH_WIKIDATA|y}}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm onto something!

Answer (score -2):

I highly recomend you to filter the year from date using **RegularExpression** instead of trying to get only the year.